# Check Duplicate Array

Tags: php, javascript

I have 10 input or more and need to check for this array do not duplicate.
if duplicate entry from user will be show that error to user too.

### sample

Check array qty[]
if dup. will be show and can not entry

```
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')"  value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')"  value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')"  value="0" size="5">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" class="InputBox" id="<? echo "qty".$i?>" onBlur="sumTotal('qty[]')" onChange="sumTotal('qty[]')" value="0" size="5">
```

I am try in 1 weeklate till now can not. Please help me.

Best Regards,
Vilart

Comment: So you want to see if there are duplicates in the `qty` array, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
// $qty is the array you want to check for duplicates
$has_duplicates = (count(array_unique($qty)) != count($qty));

if ($has_duplicates) {
   // do something
}
```